# Can't run py files by using hot key in sublimetext3

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I have update my sublime3 to newest version, then I can't  use hotkey to run my py files. Here is my hot key configuration:

```
[
{
    "caption": "Tmpl: Create python",
    "command": "sublime_tmpl",
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+p"], "args": {"type": "python"}
},
{
    "keys":["f1"],
    "caption": "SublimeREPL: Python",
    "command": "run_existing_window_command", "args":
    {
        "id": "repl_python",
        "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
    }
},
{
    "keys":["f2"],
    "caption": "SublimeREPL: Python - RUN current file",
    "command": "run_existing_window_command", "args":
    {
        "id": "repl_python_run",
        "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
    }
},
```

]

[image: hot key configuration for my sublimeREPL]

When I press <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F1</kbd>, there is nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Sublime Text 3 build 3200 has broken the `run_existing_window_command` command. As alluded to in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55189243/4019245) the solution is to instead invoke the command that the SublimeREPL menu item is using.

If you navigate to your Sublime Text 3 packages directory (`AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/` by default on Windows), you can see the packages you have installed. From this directory, if you open `SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu`, you'll see a big ole json file that looks something like this:

```
[
     {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL",
            "mnemonic": "R",
            "id": "SublimeREPL",
            "children":
            [
                {"caption": "Python",
                "id": "Python",

                 "children":[
                    {"command": "repl_open",
                     "caption": "Python",
                     "id": "repl_python",
                     "mnemonic": "P",
                     "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u"],
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "python",
                        "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                        }
                    }
   <---snip--->
                ]}
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

Notice that the innermost `children` key is a list of dictionaries with `command`s and `args`. We're going to copy those into the `sublime-keymap` file and replace the `command` and `args` that are already there. For example, your shortcut to open a python REPL would now look like:

```
"keys": ["f1"],
"command": "repl_open",
"args": {
    "type": "subprocess",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file_basename"],
    "cwd": "$file_path",
    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
    "external_id": "python",
    "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
}
```

Hitting `F1` should now work like it used to.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend.